# Prompt user input, time 4 seconds and prompt again

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `testNumbers = [1, 3, 8, 6, 9, 7]`.

What I want to do now is to make the user prompt a input and check if that input is equal to `testNumbers(1)`, if it is do something (for later, %do something) and after 4 seconds continue to make the user input a number again but this time check if `testNumbers(2)` is equal to the user prompt. This will then continue until the `length(testNumbers)` has ended.

Can this be done? I assume a for loop has to be used, but I am totally new and therefore a example would be great. Then I can continue building this.

A example:

```
testNumbers = [1, 3, 8, 6, 9, 7]
```

1. A timer starts (4sec)
2. User inputs 1 within t <= 4 sec
3. Do something like disp('Correct')
4. User inputs 3 within t <= 4 sec
5. Do something like disp('Correct')
6. User should input 8 but time runs out
7. Do something like disp('time run out')
8. User inputs 5 within t <= 4 sec but is wrong, shall be 6
9. Do something like disp('Wrong')
10. Continue like this until the matrix ends...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tic` and `toc` to measure the elapsed time between two points. You can place the `tic` before the user input (to start the timer), and then use a `toc` wherever you want to check the time that has elapsed since that point. You can use multilple `toc`'s and they will all refer to the closest `tic`.

```
% Start the timer
tic

% Prompt the user for input
value = input('Enter a number:');

elapsed_time = toc;

% If the response took more than 4 seconds
if elapsed_time > 4
    disp('took too long')
end
```

If instead (as your title states) you want to wait 4 seconds, you can use `pause` to pause execution of your program for a given amount of time

```
input('Enter a number:');

pause(4)    % Pause for 4 seconds

% Do something else
```

Comment: I have changed my title. Is it possible to get the time elapsed between each tic and toc?

Comment: @Lasse That's precisely what `toc` returns. Updated to be a little clearer

Comment: I get it. Is it possible to abort the prompt if time runs out? Like: if elapsed_time > 4
- abort prompt -
-do something -

Right now the user can input stuff even though time is out. Can I prevent it or at least disp something in between?

Comment: @Lasse There's no way to programmatically terminate a running command in MATLAB unfortunately. You could change your command line prompt into a dialog box though and try to do something [like this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96229-how-can-i-have-a-dialog-box-or-user-prompt-with-a-time-out-period)

Comment: Will do that. Thanks.